# Go back to last viewed location in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In VSCode, you can use <kbd>Alt + Left Arrow</kbd> to "Go Back" (which is essentially is to go back to last viewed location)

I am aware that in WebStorm we have "navigate last edit location", but that is not the same as go back to last viewed location.

Is there an equivalent to go back to last viewed location in WebStorm?

Comment: `Navigate | Back` does that -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#find_cursor_edit (*"To see the previous caret position, select `Navigate | Back` from the main menu or press `Ctrl+Alt+Left`"*)

Comment: The same on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5515968457490-Go-back-to-last-viewed-location-in-webstorm

Answer (score 0):

Look in the 'navigate' menu, there's back and forward menu entries there, it should also tell you the shortkey commands to do the same. On a mac it's

`command-[`